# What is the ratio between IEEE single-column double-spaced drafts and printed double-column papers?

Tags: ieeetran

What is the rough ratio between single-column double-spaced initial submission drafts in `\documentclass[journal,draftclsnofoot,onecolumn,12pt,twoside]{IEEEtran}` and IEEE double-column printed papers?
Some places it is said to be 3 to 1 and other places 2 to 1.

Comment: **(a)**  You have several questions that have answers but no accepted answer. Changing this may increase your chance of getting help. **(b)** If I were you, I would just test it myself! Take https://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum or https://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext and create some test documents. Unless I do not get your question. In addition, it will probably depend on the number of pictures and equations etc.

Comment: Even though the question does not show much research effort and has no MWE, it is clear what is being asked and how to provide an answer. I'm voting to leave open.